# 2004 Suburban brake pedal goes to the floor

Tags: chevrolet, brakes, suburban

Replaced power booster and the brake pedal goes to the floor after turning on vehicle

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You replaced which part? The hyrdroboost, or the brake master cylinder? Have you opened the brake lines at all, anywhere along the way?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a air in fluid or a brake master cylinder seal inner issue. Was the correct booster installed also could effect the outcome. Oh I’m sorry I just remembered on some of those older Chevys manually bleeding is not sufficient u have to get in with a scan tool and run an auto bleed in the abs motor. Hope this helps.